# Regular Expression for Alphanumeric characters and - / only

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to work on a regular expression in javascript that allows alphanumeric characters excludes most unique characters except - /

```
validateDesc: function(desc) {
    var matches = /^[a-zA-Z\d\-_.,\s]+$/;
    return matches.test(desc);
}
```

The one above I've tried to make only allowing alphanumeric, what do I have to add to make that happen? If anyone could give any insight on how to add other unique characters as well that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you left out the starting and ending /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions need delimiters. And be sure to include `/` if you want that to match.

```
validateDesc: function(desc) {
  var matches = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_., \t\/]+$/;
  return matches.test(desc);
}
```